# Is there any Mql command to print the connection between two admin objects?

Tags: mql

In Enovia Mql, if we want to print the details of a connection between a person and its company object what is the command. For Ex: Business objects can be explored using "Expand", similarly what is the way for Admin Objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we need some clarification on question as when you talk about "connection between a person and its company object" that means you are talking about business objects. 
But for admin objects query is different.
I will try to answer both the questions.

A. Admin object query

```
print person PERSONNAME;
```

B. Business object information:
as you need all connection information below query will help you.

```
expand bus Person PERSONNAME - type Company select rel id attribute.value;
```

as we have mentioned "type Company" the expand will only consider connected Company type of objects.

"select rel" clause selects information from relationships.
You can add any selectable for relationship in above query.

also for more information on expand you can use following query in mql and check expand bus section.

```
help bus;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to perform below query:

Print person XYZ selectable;

Thanks_Sachin

Comment: Can you provide sample output, and point out the specific parts mentioned by the question?

Comment: Please try perform below query:  print person XYZ selectable; it will fetch all selectables..

Answer (score 0):

May be it would be good if you have mentioned specific admin object names.

As per current schema design admin objects are not connected in the way business object are connected. But admin objects are referenced/added to another admin object.

For example Attribute admin object is added to type object.

> `print type Part select attribute`

Similarly type admin object is added into policy admin object.

> `Print policy Engineering selet type store format;`

In above example we can see type ,store and format admin objects being referenced from policy.

Similar way each admin object is referenced/added to another admin object